# How do I update all documents that have an _id present in another collection with Mongo?

Tags: mongodb

having 2 collections, docIdsToUpdate and docs, how can I get the list of ids from the first collection and update a field in the second one.

docIdsToUpdate:

```
_id: xxxx
docId: 1
_id: yyyy
docId: 2
```

docs

```
_id: 1
name: "test"
deleted: false
_id: 2
name: "test 2"
deleted: false
_id: 3
name: "test 3"
deleted: false
```

Is there a way to set deleted:true for ids present in the first collection using the command line? Preferably without having to run a script in node but that is an alternative.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `$merge` to perform the update. Perform a `$lookup` and some wrangling, then `merge` to the `docs` collection.

```js
db.docs.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "docIdsToUpdate",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "docId",
      "as": "update"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$update"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "deleted": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "update"
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "docs",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/neTKduz00Nh) for your reference.